# "npm uninstall" Vs "npm uninstall --save"

Tags: npm

"npm uninstall packageName" removes the package and also updates the package.json file.

But from the npm doc -

> To remove a package from the dependencies in package.json, use the --save flag. Include the scope if the package is scoped.

Can somebody clarify what --save flag actually does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--save` flag indicates that module record will be removed from package.json.
By default, if you call `uninstall` command without arguments, npm will remove the module record from package.json as well as module folder from node_modules. In the previous versions of npm you should have specified the flag explicitly.

npmjs docs:

> npm uninstall takes 3 exclusive, optional flags which save or update the package version in your main package.json:
>
> -S, --save: Package will be removed from your dependencies.
>
> -D, --save-dev: Package will be removed from your devDependencies.
>
> -O, --save-optional: Package will be removed from your optionalDependencies.
>
> --no-save: Package will not be removed from your package.json file.

Comment: Your statement "package will be removed only from node_modules folder, but record in package.json will be unchanged." is wrong. I tested in my local. When I uninstalled a package, the entry from the dependencies attribute is removed. And that's why in my question I mentioned that already.

Comment: Yes, you're right. npm changed behavior of install/uninstall commands in one of the latest version.

Comment: I'm using NPM 5.6.0. I have tested in two ways. First I manually referenced the package in package.json file and then I run "npm install". In the second test, I installed the package using "npm install packageName". When I run "npm uninstall PackageName", in both cases, the package.json file is updated accordingly. I have also checked, one package under dependencies and another one is in "devDependencies". In all cases uninstall command without --save flag behaves same. I think there is no difference in this npm version.

Comment: Interestingly, the behavior of the `--save` flag is the same for `npm install` as it is for `npm uninstall` (i.e., whether you include it or not, the package gets removed from node_modules and also from package.json) - yet it's still mentioned in the [uninstall](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-uninstall) docs, but not in the [install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) docs.